# How to include the radiation from a surface in a heat flow PDE?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a PDE were the temperature distribution T[t,x,y] is to be determined. The region is a cross section of a (glass) plate. On one side I heat using a Neumann condition, on the opposite side I want to cool by convection and radiation, also using NeumannValue. I now get stuck with implementing the radiation as this is dependend on T^4. The NeumannValue, according to reference only allows g-q u. In my case u=T. When I just use T^4 in the NeumannValue the error NeumannValue condition is invalid is issued. 
**Is there a way to simulate the temperature distribution of a glass plate including the radiation losses in Mathematica?**

Here is the code I have so far:

```
\[CapitalOmega] = ImplicitRegion[True, {{x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 30}}];
op = \[Rho] c \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(T[t, x, y]\)\) - k*\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(T[t, x, 
       y]\)\) /. {\[Rho] -> 2200 (*kg/m^3*), c -> 800 (*J/kg/K*), 
    k -> 1.4(*W/m/K*)};
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], N] = 
   NeumannValue[(*radiation*)  -0.9*5.67*10^ -8(*W/K^4/m^2*)*
      T[t, x, y]^4(*K^4*)+ 0.9*5.67*10^-8(*W/K^4/m^2*)*295^4(*K^4*), 
    2 <= y <= 28 && x == 5] +
   NeumannValue[1500 (*W/m^2 source term*), 9 <= y <= 21 && x == 0];
uifHeat = 
  NDSolveValue[{op == Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], N], 
    T[0, x, y] == 295(*K*)}, 
   T, {t, 0, 300}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  uifHeat[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] uifHeat["ElementMesh"], 
  ColorFunction -> own, Contours -> 20, AspectRatio -> 2, 
  PlotRange -> All], {{t, 10}, 0, 100, 2}]
```

Comment: I am afraid that answer is "No". At least, not directly. To the best of my knowledge Mma presently has no nonlinear PDE solver as yet, while a nonlinear boundary condition (~T^4) makes the whole problem nonlinear.

Comment: Well, not what I was hoping for. But at least I have understood the documentation right.